# Choosing the best matching item from set according to some metric

Tags: algorithm, set, complexity-theory, matching

I face with following problem:

I have list of p items (n-dimensional vectors) A and other set of q items B with metric which describes how "good matching" is that set B (it's some value). Now, I would like to exchange one item from B with one item from A to improve measure describes by mentioned metric.

I'm looking for some efficient algorithm than brute force method which in this example has complexity p x q + complexity of computing metric's value. Maybe reducing complexity would be possible by observing particular coordinates of items?

I will be grateful for any help.

Edit:
Let's say that I have barcodes of set B before and after exchange. I could compute for example Wasserstein metric between them, but it doesn't contribute to much, I guess. So let's say that metric of B is just average lenght of bars in its barcode.

Comment: Without knowing anything about the metric, you can't do better than brute forcing all q choose p+q possibilities.

Comment: Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What is the barcode of a set / n-dimensional vector?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the metric is a single value computed only from the items in _B_?

Comment: @Svante That's at least my understanding as well. But yeah, would be good if the OP clarified that.

Comment: @Svante, yes, metric is computed only for B. In this example it's average lenght of bars in barcode for B. Barcode for B proceed from computing persistence classes from data cloud (vectors in B)

Comment: @user6808217 I have no idea what you are talking about. (Persistence classes? Data cloud?) Your question lacks so much context, I could parse that with a regex.

Comment: Given what you told @Svante, this problem is identical to finding the maximum-metric  subset of `A \union B` with size `q`.  If that's the case, you should rewrite the question that way. It would be _much_ easier to understand. But it will still be impossible to give an answer better than brute force unless you state exactly what the data space and metric are.

Answer (score 0):

In order to even attempt to answer this, I have to make assumptions. It is of course, quite possible that my assumptions are wrong, so please clarify where I have a misunderstanding. Fortunately, I can re-cast my assumptions in terms of code, and therefore, make my assumptions at least, (mostly) unambiguous.

If I have the question correct, you have a list (e.g. java.util.List) of n-dimensional vectors of some unspecified item type (real numbers?) called A. In code:

```
List<Item[]> A
assert(A.size() == p)
```

In addition, you have a set (e.g., java.util.Set, but I suspect you just really mean a collection of some sort that you might be hoping to index) of items that is B - and there are q of them. In code:

```
Collection<Item[]> B
assert(B.size() == q)
```

In addition, you have some function - which I will call "Measure" - which computes a "metric" value for B. Now, I have to issue a warning, because "metric" is a very specific mathematical term which defines distance measurements between two elements of a metric space. Sometimes, one can use the "metric" for a an element of a metric space to describe its distance from an origin point i.e., the point [0,0,0,...0]. If you are indeed describing operations on a metric space, there may be possible improvements on the approach. In any case, the "measure" function takes B as input and returns a real-valued number.  i.e., :

```
double Measure(Collection<Item[]> B) {
  // Compute value ...
}
```

Now, if I understand correctly, a brute-force (and not really efficient even for brute-force) approach to solving your problem might look like this:

```
Collection<Item[]> replaceItem(Collection<Item[]> c, Item[] removed, Item[] added) {
   Collection<Item[]> replacement = c.clone();
   // Technically, this might not work. Not sure offhand if an Array of
   // items qualifies as Comparable even if the Items are comparable.
   // But conceptually, the idea below is correct.
   replacement.remove(removed);
   replacement.add(added);
   return replacement;
}

double MeasureWithReplacement(Collection<Item[]> B, Item[] b, Item[] a) {
  // brute-force implementation. An improvement would be to implement
  // the original Measure function with the Measure function knowing how
  // to do this replacement.
  Collection<Item[]> replacement = replaceItem(B, b, a);
  return Measure(replacement);
}

Collection<Item[]> ImproveBUsingA(Collection<Item[]> B, List<Item[]> A) {
  double bestValue = Measure(B);
  Item[] bestRemoved = null;
  Item[] bestAdded = null;
  for (Item[] b : B) {
    for (Item[] a : A) {
      double currentMeasure = MeasureWithReplacement(B, b, a);
      if (currentMeasure > bestValue) {
        bestValue = currentMeasure;
        bestRemoved = b;
        bestAdded = a;
      }
    }
  }

  return (bestRemoved == null ? B : replaceItem(B, bestRemoved, bestAdded));
}
```

This now forms the problem statement as I understand it: Can we get a big-O improvement on this algorithm?

I will assume that it is fairly trivial to perform the operation without the extra cloning of the Collection, so with that assumption, the operation here, is as you suggested, O(|A|*|B|*Complexity(Measure(|B|))).

**One possible improvement:** 
Try calculating Measure using a saved result and then using just the differently presented replacement item operations to shrink the cost of calculating Measure. In other words create something like this:

```
double MeasureFromBase(Collection<Item[]> base, double baseMeasure, Item[] a, Item[] b) {
  // Do calculation here, but use a and b to provide deltas compared to
  // baseMeasure
  ...
}
```

This would reduce the cost of doing the Measure operation, assuming that replacing items in the collection allowed simple measurements. Still, the complexity is O(|A|*|B|*Complexity(MeasureFromBase(|B|)), which does not get you what you are really hoping for.

**In order to get any real sort of improvement, we have to know more about Item[] and the Measure calculation.**

In particular, it would be helpful to know if some of the elements of Item[] are more important than others. Is the first element of Item[] the most important? Is the kth element? Are they of equal importance? If a particular element of Item[] dominates the calculation, you can do a kind of branch-and-bound calculation where you first calculate the metric based on the most important metric, and then, use secondary and tertiary measurements only if needed. (See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis for a useful tool in this regard).

Also, can two Item values be compared? Can I determine item1 <= item2? If so, and if their relative comparison values relates to their effect on the overall Measure value, you might be able to build a kind of index for the operations.

As it is, nothing more can be determined. Still, I hope that this helps.